# how to Resize the parent div depending on the width and number of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a responsive Slide show where the user can upload any number of images, and the application dynamically generates a slide show that can fit in any device. Now there is a problem i am facing here

```
<section id="container">
            <article id="slider">
           <div id="item"><img src="img/image-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div id="item"><img src="img/image-2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div id="item"><img src="img/image-3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div id="item"><img src="img/image-4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div id="item"><img src="img/image-3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div id="item"><img src="img/image-4.jpg" alt="" /></div>

            </article>
            <article id="nav">
                <div id="prev" onclick="prev();"><img src="img/prev.png" alt="" /></div>
                <div id="next" onclick="next();"><img src="img/next.png" alt="" /></div>
            </article>
        </section>
```

The above  Html code is generated by my java code. Here the user has uploaded 5 images. Now each image will occupy a fixed with of 300 px. so total width will be 5*300+5*padding. Now i can set the width of the container dynamically in my java code to fit all the images in a single row, and hide the ones the exceed 940px, as seen in most normal slide shows. I want know whether there is a css solution to this like shrink wrapping which shrinks the inline divs, here i want to expand the container.

Regards,

Maclean

Comment: try using overflow to hidden.. in css

Comment: hidden will work if a put and the images in a single container and then put the container within another container.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest use `display:inline-block` to inner elements, and `white-space:nowrap` for outer div. If you can create a jsfiddle that would be helpful to show code changes.

Comment: The problem is not with aligning  in a single row. Its about the container width. If the container with is 30px. if i try to fit 3 images within the container they will all be aligned column wise. In looking for property that can automatically re-size container width

Comment: @MacleanPinto white-space:nowrap is just for that

Comment: white-space:no wrap will wrap elements if all the images are included in a single div. Not individual div

Comment: then you should use display:inline-block to divs, instead of images